# Where can I ask about WinterBash 2015 hats

Tags: discussion

So, I earned a secret hat (won't tell which one, is a secret), but I can't find or figure out how did i get it. In the description it only says "this is a secret hat".

Where can I ask about hats? is it a new Stack Site or something?

Comment: [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats)

Comment: Thanks, post as answer? So if anyone else wants to know, its easier to look the answer and not the comments

Comment: (Just saying: there're already quite many answers on Flip Flop in that thread)

Comment: I'm sad I wont be able to get the *It's over 9000*

Comment: FeelsBadMan @Braiam

Comment: You can also look into the chats, people are usually active about this discussion in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and check out the [Winter Bash 2015 tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash-2015).

Secret hats are being discussed in [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats).